Buck Converter Peak Current Mode Control Average Model
I am trying to understand average model of Buck Converter for Peak Current Mode Control Topology.
Below snapshot taken from Christophe Basso Webpage(https://powersimtof.com/Spice.htm)  from file "PWM Switch LTspice: Mark Dimattina".

Now my question is what is parameter rAmp and Se?
I tried to contact vendor for particular controller how should I get these values and following is the reply
"The slope is linear with a ramp of 53mVxDuty Cycle (relative to the sense pins), or 0.7VxDuty Cycle (relative to VITH)"
Now when I try to correlate with above image I got confused, which data should I use in place of rAmp and Se?
Second question ,what is parameter Ri(above rAmp) and what is R2(20m) ?

It seems that slope compensation $S_e$ in [V]/[s], is evaluated based on a parameter called $r_{Amp}$ and $S_e$ according to $S_e=r_{Amp}F_{s}$ with $F_s$ the switching frequency. In the example, setting $r_{Amp}$ to 0.1m gives a compensation slope of 100u x 50 = 5 V/s which is very small (no compensation). Digging up the model .LIB will certainly explain why it was done this way but I believe this is the basic idea for compensating this model.

@Verbal Kint ...Many thanks for your response! unfortunately it does not have .lib files .could you please help me with few more questions   1.) I am not able to understand the statement given by manufacturer "The slope is linear with a ramp of 53mVxDuty Cycle (relative to the sense pins), or 0.7VxDuty Cycle (relative to VITH)"           ...this  0.7V x Duty cycle , why its multiplied by duty cycle not frequency in both case? I am bit confused here .     2) Ri has been mentioned as simply sense resistor ,isn't it should be Ri= Sense Resistor * Current Amplifier gain ?

I looked at the specs and the data-sheet does not give enough information. To model the circuit, you should know the equivalent sense resistance and the attenuation between the control pin and the current sense comparator. What they say is that you have a ramp reducing the peak setpoint linearly with the on-time duration. The Vc to Ipeak gain they give is not enough because they surely internally divide the Vc level before reaching the comparator. I wrote this AN and you will see what is missing from ADI's datasheet.

Many Thanks sir for your response !! The controller I am talking about here is LTC3890 , for this controller we are using external sense resistor of 6.5mohm.

I think it means there is an effective gain from the current sense inputs of 0.7V/53mV (Av = 13.2). So the sense resistor Ri should be 6.5mOhm x 13.2 (85.85 mOhm) and the rAmp value should be 0.7V.

